# My server returns 404 to files with accent(non english character) ubuntu 16.04

Tags: wordpress, url, apache2, ubuntu-16.04

When I try to open a link file with accent(non english character), my server returns an error 404: 
[www.pennacorp.com.br/B2B%20-%20Conex%C3%B5es%20com%20filiais.pdf](https://www.pennacorp.com.br/downloads/docs/user/B2B%20-%20Conex%C3%B5es%20com%20filiais.pdf)

But the file exists on my server. I can see it using FTP: 
[Eg. Image - B2B - Conexões com filiais](https://i.stack.imgur.com/StnMB.png)

---

**MORE INFORMATIONS**

I have two ubuntu servers with differents versions:

- It is on Ubuntu 16.04, where error 404 is returned
- On ubuntu 14.04, the link file works normally: 
  [www.pennatec.com.br/B2B%20-%20Conex%C3%B5es%20com%20filiais.pdf](https://www.pennatec.com.br/downloads/docs/user/B2B%20-%20Conex%C3%B5es%20com%20filiais.pdf)

Comment: Are you sure it has anything to do with the special characters? Test if it works with another name.

Comment: @mathiasfk unfortunately I need to use the special character, end other files without special characters work normally
[other file](https://www.pennacorp.com.br/downloads/docs/user/CONTAS%20A%20PAGAR%20-%20Como%20Criar%20Substituicao%20de%20Duplicatas.pdf)